# getting socket error with tweepy python library

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I am trying to make twitter search and get tweets about particular keyword. I have Below Codes.

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

ckey = 'acVL....'
csecret = 'qq0W1qdIr24XzCuX...'
atoken = '439474342-ZJfFqM4oZ8Y8....p'
asecret = 'Y9MKssDKs8IHIJMhNJCmyUCE3...'

class listener(StreamListener):

 def on_data(self, data):
    print data
    return True

 def on_error(self, status):
    print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["sample_word"])
```

When i try to run this code i am getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tw.py", line 22, in <module>
    twitterStream.filter(track=["secretcv"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 316, in filter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 237, in _start
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 157, in _run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1172, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Do I miss something? Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: From @RohitJ- From your machine, are you able to ping the domain or access the firehose directly through the web browser? This error message normally occurs when you're having problems either with your DNS or internet service.

Comment: not using proxy it is a vm machine

Comment: twitterStream.filter(track=["sample_word"]) when change double quote to single quote problem solved. but this time even credentials are correct i am always getting 401 response